# Retrofit error URL query string must not have replace block when provide dynamically values

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to get JSON data using retrofit get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string
>   "q={text}&langpair={l_from}|{l_to}" must not have replace block. For
>   dynamic query parameters use @Query.

My code is

```
    // example of my site
    // http://mytempsite.com/get?q=hello friend&langpair=en|ur

    @GET("get?q={text}&langpair={from}|{to}")
    Call<ApiService> getJsonData(@Query("text") String text,
                                 @Query("from") String from,
                                 @Query("to") String to);
```

And my calling request

```
Call<ApiService> call = apiService.getJsonData("hello word","en","ur");
```

But when i use statically like this it will work.

```
@GET("get?q=Hello Word&langpair=en|ur")
        Call<ApiService> getJsonData(@Query("text") String text,
                                     @Query("from") String from,
                                     @Query("to") String to);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this code:

```
@GET(".")
Call<ApiService> getJsonData(@Query("q") String text,
                             @Query("langpair") String langpair);

Call<ApiService> call = apiService.getJsonData("hello word","en|ur");
```

Comment: thanks: error is remove but does not return anything, only blank activity?

Comment: instead of @GET("."), i use @GET("get?") now working thanks